# HTML image won't show but href works

Tags: html, image, href

The following tag shows a white box (broken image), but if I click on it the browser loads the image and displays it.

```
<a href="/nicks/pic.png"><img height="24" width="24" scr="/nicks/pic.png"/> </a>
```

I have tried permission and so forth, and moved the directory.

Comment: remove the trailing slash in the url

Comment: Never mind, I am a muppet.  It's just gone midnight here, and the problem is the classic typo.  src and scr  (shame on me)

Comment: its a typo, good you solved it, time to get some rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct attribute name is `src`.
Don't use `scr`. Use `src`.

Comment: Thanks guys :-)   I hate to say it but I spent an hour pulling my hair out of this one.  The dangers of copying and pasting.  One simple re-type was all it took to show me the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use "src" instead of "scr".
src is short for "source". I've made this mistake myself too many times :)
An easy way to remember this is `<img src="#">` stands for Image Source :)